# Why doesn't this tee with process substitution produce the 1st and chosen lines?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, tee, process-substitution

What I want is printing the output the first line ( table head ) of `ps aux` and the grep result.

After search, I come up with following.

```
ps aux | tee >(head -1 > /dev/tty) | grep mongo
```

But I find the stdin of `grep mongo` is cut off.

Also, if I omit `> /dev/tty`, what will the stdout of `head -1` direct to? Why isn't it the console?

(Yes, I know I can achive my purpose by command `awk`. I am just curious about why my command doesn't work?)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a dupe of the question it was closed as a dupe of. This one is asking why something doesn't work as expected, The other is asking how to accomplish a specific task.

Comment: Take a look at [Thor's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47922/977) to the other question; he covers why your approach doesn't work, and a way to make it (somewhat) work. (I don't blame you for missing it, it's nowhere near the top. I missed it myself at first, too.)

Comment: Also see a followup asked about that: [How do I use tee to redirect to grep?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47932/how-do-i-use-tee-to-redirect-to-grep/47934)

Comment: Thanks @derobert the two links solve my question. I think I have more specific keyword to search to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` to match two things at the same time:

- The first line.
- The line containing "mongo".

There you go:

```
$ ps aux | awk 'NR == 1 || /mongo/ {print $0}'
```

- The `NR == 1` condition matches the first line.
- The `/mongo/` condition matches lines containing "mongo".
- `{print $0}` is the action associated with the two previous conditions, in this case: print the whole line.