# Bash: How to get stdout to console and also pipe to next command?

Tags: bash

How to get stdout to console and pipe to next command at the same time?

I've tried using the Read command as suggested here which worked to get the output of Grep from a Tail of a log file to a variable and then to a log or email, but I'd still like to get the output to stdout console as well:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365222/346155

I've tried using Tee as here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47936/346155

I'm using the --line-buffered flag just in case from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162898/4240654

I may be missing something simple about the sdtin logic, but the case from the first link suggests that Bash may not have this simple capability. And that variables cannot read from a subshell.

The fact that `echo 'hello' | echo $(</dev/stdin)` works, suggests it might be possible. Another way to look at it is, how can I stdout to console within each pipe segment. That should help to debug a long chain of commands, before committing it to a bash script.

EDITS:
Something like `echo 'hello' | echo $(</dev/stdin) >/dev/stout` or `echo 'hello' | tee >/dev/stdout | echo 2nd $(</dev/stdin)`, the latter should output 'hello' twice, but only does so once.

Comment: How did you use `tee`?

Comment: I was able to Tee to a log file, but not yet to Stdout console.

Comment: Do you want this `echo hello  | tee >(grep -o h)`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk In total I want it to ```(tail log) | grep "keyword" | tee>*OutToConsole* | (read var | echo var | mail )``` so I can see the alert line also before it emails.....YES, that was what I was missing.. Grep in a subshell does stsout to console Thanks! .. for the record, so does Echo.

Comment: `tail log | grep "keyword" | tee >(mail)`?

Comment: Actually even ```generateOutput | tee >(grep "keyword") | thenDoOtherStuff``` works. The linked answer regarding Tee I think was too specific to abstract to a general case.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, go ahead and answer in the general case and I will accept. I suppose the question could also be how to output to stdout without a subshell, but someone can try answering that.

Comment: The command you showed will not print output of `grep`, check: `echo stuff | tee >(grep -o s) | wc -c`

Comment: `>/dev/stdout` -- redirect stdout to stdout.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, how interesting, I thought that solved it, but ```echo 'hello' | tee >(echo hello) | echo 2nd $(</dev/stdin)``` gives 2 hellos, but in a different order. Grep in place of Echo does the same. I think using Tee as with Kamil's answer is probably the most direct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `tee /dev/tty`. Example:

```
echo "Hello word" | tee /dev/tty | wc -c
```

[`tee`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) and [`/dev/tty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html) are required by POSIX.

---

In general you can use a name like `/dev/tty2` or `/dev/pts/7`. It doesn't have to be the current terminal, if only you can write to it.

> Another way to look at it is, how can I stdout to console within each pipe segment. That should help to debug a long chain of commands, before committing it to a bash script.

I have done something similar conveniently with `tmux` panes. You can do this with or without `tmux`.

1. Prepare as many panes as you need; or console windows, if you prefer.
2. In each invoke `tty` to learn the filename of the terminal.
3. In one of them invoke the pipeline you want to debug, using `tee` and a different terminal in each step. This pipeline

   ```
   command1 | command2 | command3
   ```

   will become something like

   ```
   command1 | tee /dev/pts/4 | command2 | tee /dev/pts/5 | command3
   ```

   where `/dev/pts/4` and `/dev/pts/5` are additional terminals (e.g. panes in `tmux`).

Comment: You can do that even when not run from a terminal `{ echo "Hello word" | tee /dev/fd/7 | wc -c; } 7>&1` (ok, not POSIX, and will NOT work on FreeBSD by default). Notice that `/dev/tty` or `/dev/pts/N` do not always work: `su other_user -c 'echo hi | tee /dev/tty | wc -c'` => `tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address`. But it's not clear for me that it's this that the OP is after ;-)

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for! @mosvy, there may be special cases where it doesnt work, and good to know it will translate into a script. What is 7 again?

Answer (score 1):

`... | tee log-file-name`

This take the stdout of the first command and copies to the log file, and to stdout.