# Pipe partial output of background process and store it in variable

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, variable, background-process

### Background:

I'm working on a project in which a server is started at a random available port. The server is started by a command:

```
node server.js
```

Once the server is ready and starts serving on an available port, it outputs (along with a bunch of other logs) the complete server URL (including port number) on stdout in the following form:

```
Server started! Listening on URL: http://localhost:12927
```

This server process keeps running until you manually kill it (and keeps printing some other logs).

### Actual problem:

I'm writing a script to start the server and then listen to its output. As soon as I get the message something like `"Server started! Listening on URL: [SERVER_URL]"`, I want to store this `SERVER_URL` in a variable and process later in the script (e.g. open a browser for automation testing).

### What I've tried:

Having only a very basic understanding of Bash, I've tried the following options (of course, after researching on SE):

1. I researched a bit about using `grep` with regex. This works pretty well if I do it manually (i.e. not storing it to variable and just piping from an `echo` command.

   ```
   SERVER_URL=$(node server.js | grep -m 1 -ohP 'Server started! Listening on URL: \K([^\s$]*)')
   ```

However, it kinda blocks on this line, probably it's waiting for the node server to get killed. My requirement is clear: I want to populate SERVER_URL from the server's output without waiting for it beyond the point it spits out that URL on stdout.

2. I also fiddled around a bit with [redirection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47936/15788) and [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58968358/155813). I learnt that the pipe actually waits for the source process to get completed. I've tried to do the following with redirection, but it's not working:

   ```
   SERVER_URL=$(node server.js >&3 | grep -m 1 -ohP 'Server started! Listening on URL: \K([^\s$]*)')
   ```

It is throwing some weird "Unhandled 'error' event" exception (Error: write EPIPE).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in:

```
var=$(cmd | grep -m1 pattern)
```

`cmd`'s stdout is a pipe to `grep`, and `grep`'s stdout is a pipe to the shell.

After `grep` has found the first match, it outputs it on its stdout and exits.

The shell will read `grep`'s output, see end-of-file when `grep` exits, but in the case of `bash`, the shell will also wait for `cmd` to exit.

Now, because `grep` has exited, `cmd`'s stdout is now a broken pipe. So the next time `cmd` writes to stdout, it will receive a SIGPIPE signal and die.

Here, the question is, what do you want to do with the rest of `cmd`'s output once you've read up to the first line that matches the pattern?

If you're not interested in it you could run a background `cat` command that reads it and discards it:

```
{
   url=$(grep -m1 -oP 'Server started! Listening on URL: \K\S+')
   cat <&0 > /dev/null & # <&0 to work around the fact that bash redirects
                         # background commands stdin from /dev/null
} < <(node server.js)
```

If you want to keep it, you could redirect it to some file, and use `tail -f` for instance in the shell to wait for the URL message:

```
node server.js > server.log &
{
  IFS= read -r pid
  url=$(grep -m1 -oP 'Server started! Listening on URL: \K\S+')
  kill -- "$pid"
} < <(echo "$BASHPID"; exec tail -n +1 -f server.log)
```

Here passing the pid of tail so as to kill it after the message is found rather than waiting for `tail` to be killed by a SIGPIPE which may never happen if `tail` never outputs anything else.

Comment: Thanks @stéphane-chazelas! Both of the options worked exactly as you mentioned. I think I understood the first option, but the commands seem pretty advanced to me. It'll be great if you can point me to some reference doc / learning material from where I can get details about these commands and learn more about it.

Comment: The canonical documentation is the man pages, e.g. run `man cat` to see the `cat` documentation and use `q` to quit. Google `linux man pages` for links. Here's a freely available book that I like: [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/index.php)