# A hidden process, what it is?

Tags: linux, proc

```
[root@datacenteronline ~]# ssh root@192.168.1.172
Last login: Wed Apr 17 09:55:45 2013 from 192.168.1.187
[root@localhost ~]# ls /proc/ | grep 2266
[root@localhost ~]# cd /proc/2266
[root@localhost 2266]# ls
attr             cpuset   limits      net            root       statm
autogroup        cwd      loginuid    numa_maps      sched      status
auxv             environ  maps        oom_adj        schedstat  syscall
cgroup           exe      mem         oom_score      sessionid  task
clear_refs       fd       mountinfo   oom_score_adj  smaps      wchan
cmdline          fdinfo   mounts      pagemap        stack
coredump_filter  io       mountstats  personality    stat
[root@localhost 2266]# ls -al /proc/2266
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x   7 apache apache 0 Apr 17 09:45 .
dr-xr-xr-x 266 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:11 ..
dr-xr-xr-x   2 apache apache 0 Apr 17 09:45 attr
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 autogroup
-r--------   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 auxv
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 cgroup
--w-------   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 clear_refs
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 cmdline
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 coredump_filter
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 cwd -> /
-r--------   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 environ
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 exe -> /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
dr-x------   2 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 fd
dr-x------   2 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 fdinfo
-r--------   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 io
-rw-------   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 limits
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 loginuid
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 maps
-rw-------   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 mem
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 mountinfo
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 mounts
-r--------   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 mountstats
dr-xr-xr-x   6 apache apache 0 Apr 17 09:45 net
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 numa_maps
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 oom_adj
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 oom_score
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 oom_score_adj
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 pagemap
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 personality
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 root -> /
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 sched
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 schedstat
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 sessionid
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 smaps
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 stack
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 stat
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 statm
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 status
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 syscall
dr-xr-xr-x  29 apache apache 0 Apr 17 09:45 task
-r--r--r--   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 wchan
```

Cound anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: is `ls` an alias for something? does `/bin/ls -1 | grep 2266` behave the same way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is likely to be a thread. In Linux, threads have a different process ID to the other threads in the process. When you look at the PID column in `ps`, you're actually looking at the thread group ID (TGID), which is common amongst all threads in a process. This is for historical reasons due to the way threads evolved in Linux.

For example, on my system, chromium has a number of threads in a process (multiple processes too):

```
$ ps -efL | grep chromium
[UID       PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD]
[...]
camh     10927  5182 10927  0    4 11:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium ...
camh     10927  5182 10929  0    4 11:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium ...
camh     10927  5182 10930  0    4 11:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium ...
camh     10927  5182 10933  0    4 11:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium ...
```

The second column is the TGID (although it is labelled as PID) and the forth column is LWP (light-weight process).

```
$ ls /proc | grep 10927
10927
$ ls /proc | grep 10929
$ cd /proc/10929
$ head -n 5 status
Name:   Chrome_ChildIOT
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   10927
Pid:    10929
PPid:   5182
```

You can see that process 10929 does not show up in `/proc`, but you can `cd` to it. If you look in the `status` file, you'll see that it is part of "process" (thread group) 10927, and from the output above, that process does appear in `/proc`.

Comment: BTW: your `ps … | grep …` line won't actually print out the header... I wish grep had an option to always print the first line! I think I'll ask a question about that.

Comment: ... actually, it's already been asked: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47918/how-to-grep-a-specific-line-and-the-first-line-of-a-file

Comment: @derobert: I know. I added it later as I felt it was useful. I wondered how long it would be before someone pointed it out. You were quick :)

Comment: Indeed, quite useful. I suggest using that final sed command from the question I posted instead. That actually prints the header line... And is a nice solution!

Comment: I'll use editorial conventions and put the non-literal output in brackets, so as to not confuse the point.

Answer (score 3):

It's an apache thread.

You can tell from this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   0 Apr 17 09:45 exe -> /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
```

The Linux kernel documentation for the proc filesystem apparently doesn't explain why the thread ID is a directory but hidden from `ls`.

However, the threads are seen in `/proc/<pid>/task/<threadid>`.