# How do I create a systemd scope for an already-existing process from the command line?

Tags: linux, systemd, d-bus, cgroups

I have a machine running the cgroups v2 (unified) hierarchy, so systemd is responsible for managing all cgroups and delegation to the systemd user instance works. I'd like to perform [resource control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) on a group of processes, so I need them together in a unit — presumably a [systemd scope](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.scope.html).

Normally, `systemd-run` would do this — but unfortunately these processes are already running and I don't want to restart them.

How can I create a [systemd scope](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.scope.html) out of already existing processes? The [Control Group Interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) documentation tells me it's possible, but I haven't been able to find a way from the command line. Neither `systemctl` nor `systemd-run` seem able to do this.

Is there a way from the command line? I am running systemd v241 if it matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are various command-line tools to make dbus calls; systemd comes with one called `busctl`. So you can call `StartTransientUnit` from the command line.

## The command

The syntax is positively annoying, but it looks like this (for one process id, 14460):

```
busctl call --user org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
       org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager StartTransientUnit 'ssa(sv)a(sa(sv))' \
       'SCOPE-NAME.scope' fail 1 PIDs au 1 14460 0
```

## Explanation

That is positively opaque (and took some tries to get right, and ultimately using `dbus-monitor` to see how `systemd-run` did it — only on the system manager though, `systemd-run --user` seems not to go through dbus). So an explanation, parameter by parameter:

```
busctl call --user                  # use user session dbus, not system   
  org.freedesktop.systemd1          # dbus service name
  /org/freedesktop/systemd1         # dbus object in that service
  org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager  # interface name in that service 
  StartTransientUnit                # method we're going to call
  'ssa(sv)a(sa(sv))'                # signature of method, see below
  'SCOPE-NAME.scope'                # first argument, name of scope
  fail                              # second argument, how to handle conflicts (see below)
  1                                 # start of third argument, number of systemd properties for unit 
  PIDs                              # name of first property
  au                                # data type of first property, (a)rray [aka list] of (u)nsigned integers
  1                                 # count of array — that is, number of pids 
  14460                             # first pid
  0                                 # fourth argument: array size=0 (unused parameter)
```

Adding to the command

### More properties

To add another systemd property to the unit, you'd increase the number of properties and add it on. Note that each property is at least three additional command-line arguments: the key, the value-type, and the value. As an example, adding a Slice property would go from:

```
… fail 1 PIDs au 1 14460 0
```

to

```
… fail 2 PIDs au 1 14460 Slice s whatever.slice 0
       ^                 ^^^^^ ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     count                key type value
```

Type "s" is string. The list of them can be found in the [D-Bus specification’s “Type system" chapter](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#type-system)

You can of course change the count to 3 and add a third property. Etc.

### More pids

Similar to more properties, but this time it's the count buried inside the "PIDs" property value. An example should make it clearer:

```
… fail 1 PIDs au 1 14460 0
```

becomes

```
… fail 1 PIDs au 2 14460 14461 0
                 ^       ^^^^^
         internal count  second pid
```

if you add PID 14461 as well as 14460.

You can add a third, fourth, etc. PID in the same way.

### Combining them

You can of course combine additional properties with additional pids. Just remember that the list of pids is a property value, so it needs to stay together. You can't mix pid arguments with other properties. The right way is to change:

```
… fail 1 PIDs au 1 14460 0
```

to:

```
… fail 2 PIDs au 2 14460 14461 Slice s whatever.slice 0
```

(the order doesn't matter, you could put the Slice block before the PIDs block).

### Where does the signature come from?

The signature is obtained either from the [systemd dbus API documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/) or, probably more easily, by using dbus introspection:

```
$ busctl introspect org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
         org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager | grep1 StartTransientUnit
NAME                  TYPE     SIGNATURE         RESULT/VALUE   FLAGS
.StartTransientUnit   method   ssa(sv)a(sa(sv))  o              -
```

(for `grep1`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279518)

There are a lot of methods and dbus-properties listed, over 180 here. So don't omit the `grep`.

### What does “fail” handling conflicts mean? What else is there?

According to the [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/) (look under "CreateUnit"), the useful values are `fail` and `replace`. `fail` means your scope will fail to start if there is some conflict. `replace` means systemd will get rid of the conflicting unit. Note that this seems to only be for units that are currently starting or scheduled to (it does say "queued") — replace won't, for example, replace an already-running scope with the same name.

Comment: Really helpful answer, thank you ... this stuff just isn't documented sufficiently and I came upon this while putting together the pieces.