# How to set what field names are displayed in listings?

Tags: command-line, configuration, ls, ps

When I execute a command in Ubuntu, which results in a listing, I get results without the field names. Example is `ls -l` or `ps l`.

I am not very experienced and always need to go digging through man pages and online documentation. And the names are quite crypcit already.

Is there a way to turn on field name listing globally i.e. for all commands?

Note: actually `ps l` shows field names, while `ls -l` does not. It is true that the second is very trivial. However, the question stands - is there a way to overwrite this behaviour?

Comment: @Vorac If you need it desperately then you can find the source code of ls add the fieldnames.It comes as a part of coreutils.    Check this out https://github.com/kurtzhong/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @StephaneChazelas stated this isn't possible. You're only other options are to modify the source (don't do this) and/or develop some wrapper scripts and aliases for yourself to assist.

There is this technique for preserving the columns of `ps` in output that you're going to pipe to `sort`.

- [sort but keep header line in the at the top?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/sort-but-keep-header-line-in-the-at-the-top)

I would take this as an opportunity to hone your alias/scripting skills by putting together the pieces that you need. Much of using Unix/Linux is in tricking out your environment so that things are more accessible to your work habits and style.

Answer (score 1):

Following [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm)'s advice, the following script might help.
 Check the following script.It will build labels for the fields in ls -l command.I have used the `column` utility (a BSD extension, but it also comes with most Linux distros).It is included in the util-linux package.

```
#!/bin/bash
{ echo Permissions links Owner Group Size Last_modMonth Last_modTime Last_modTime Filename; ls -l ; } | column -t | awk 'NR!~/^(2)$/'
ls -l | head -1
```

You can alias it and use this.