# Grep lines but let the first line through

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep, pipe

Consider the following output from `df`.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        23G  6.1G   16G  29% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           397M  420K  397M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.8G  904K  1.8G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6       890G  324G  521G  39% /home
/dev/sdb1       459G  267G  169G  62% /home/user/mnt
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

How can I only show lines that begin with `"/dev"` and keep the heading, but  filter out everything else. I'd also like to not have to resort to using using temporary files or variables?  Note: the heading is locale dependent, therefore you can't catch it with a regexp.

Comment: locale dependant maybe, but your can force the language with `LANG=C df`.

Comment: @Totor see 1_CR's [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105748/22222), that's exactly what he suggested.

Comment: This has been answered several times previously.  See e.g. `body` from http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11859/3169

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I would use a slightly more sophisticated approach than simple `grep`:

1. `awk`

   ```
   df -h | awk 'NR==1 || /^\/dev/'
   ```

   `NR` is the current line number so the `awk` scriptlet above will print if this is the first line **or** if the current line begins with `/dev`. And after posting this I see it is the same as @1_CR's answer. Oh well...
2. Perl

   ```
   df -h | perl -ne 'print if (/^\/dev/ || $.==1)'
   ```

   The same idea here, in Perl the special variable `$.` is the current line number. An alternative way would be

   ```
   df -h | perl -pe '$_="" unless /^\/dev/ || $.==1'
   ```

   The `-p` switch will print all lines of the input file. The value of the current line is held in `$_` so we set `$_` to empty unless we want the current line.
3. `sed`

   ```
   df -h | sed -n '1p; /^\/dev/p'
   ```

   The `-n` suppresses normal output so no lines are printed. The `1p` means print the first line and the `/^\/dev/p` means print any line that starts with `/dev`.

   As pointed out in the comments below, in the unlikely case where the locale on your current system causes the header line to start with `/dev`, the command above will print it twice. Stephane Chazelas [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105747/grep-lines-but-let-the-first-line-through/105752?noredirect=1#comment162155_105752) that this one will not have that problem:

   ```
   df -h | sed  -e 1b -e '/^\/dev/!d'
   ```
4. `grep`

   ```
   df -h | grep -E '^(/dev|File)'
   ```

   This might not be portable because of LOCALE problems as you said. However, I am reasonably certain that no locale or `df` version will give a path in the first line, so searching for lines that contain no `/` should also work:

   ```
   df -h | grep -E '^[^/]*$|^/dev'
   ```

Comment: Your sed one would print the 1st line twice if it started with /dev. Unlikely, but `sed -e 1b -e '/^\/dev/!d'` wouldn't have the problem.

Answer (score 15):

You are going to [run into issues attempting to parse df output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/094), however for simple cases, the following may work

```
LC_ALL=C df -P | awk 'NR == 1 || /^\/dev/'
```

Answer (score 12):

This should work as well (not tested, though):

```
df | (read a; echo "$a"; grep /dev)
```

or

```
df | (head -n 1; grep ^/dev)
```

Comment: very nice. ^/dev will limit this to lines that start with /dev. Wasn't able to do that as an an edit since I was short 9 characters

Comment: First one works, but you should echo "$a" (note quotes) or any spacing in the header will shrink down to single spaces (eg with column aligned output).

Second one does not.

Comment: @steveayre Thanks for the suggestion. Integrated it into answer.

Comment: @steveayre even `echo "$a"` is not completely safe (possible different interpretation of `-` or `\ ` ). It is always better to use `printf %s\\n "$a"` to print a string which could possibly contain the mentioned characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
df -h | tee >(head -1) >(sleep 0.5;grep ^/dev) > /dev/null;sleep 1.0
```

Comment: I just tried that; it printed the header line *first*.

Comment: @KeithThompson Why is that a problem? The accepted answers also print the header line first.

Comment: @l0b0: Sorry, I mistyped; it printed the header line *last*.

Comment: Worked correcly on my machine. Try df -h | tee >(head -1) >(sleep 0.5;grep ^/dev) > /dev/null;sleep 1.0

Comment: Anonymous edited my post and it does not work for me. 

df -h | tee >(head -n 1) | grep ^/dev

Answer (score 4):

```
df | head -n 1; df | grep ^/dev
```

Comment: Not bad, but it has the disadvantage that it invokes `df` twice.

Comment: Are we short on df invocations?

Comment: Not particularly, but there are solutions like terdon's `df -h | sed -e 1b -e '/^\/dev/!d'` that only invoke `df` once. The `df` command can hang in some circumstances; in that case, invoking it just once is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

```
df | grep -n '' | grep -E '^1:|[^:]*:/dev' | sed 's/[^:]*://'
```

The `grep -n` inserts line numbers into the stream, we then pull out the first one and the lines of interest via egrep, then remove the added numbers from the output via sed.

You can avoid the `sed` by using [positive lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (which `grep` can handle with its [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) engine (`-P`)) and `-o` which tells `grep`  to only print the matched pattern:

```
df | grep -n '' | grep -Po '(?<=^1:)(.*)|(?<=:)(/dev.*)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Take the definition of `body` from [sort but keep header line at the top](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11859/3169)

```
# print the header (the first line of input)
# and then run the specified command on the body (the rest of the input)
# use it in a pipeline, e.g. ps | body grep somepattern
body() {
    IFS= read -r header
    printf '%s\n' "$header"
    "$@"
}
```

Use it like this

```
$ df -h | body grep ^/dev
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        23G  6.1G   16G  29% /
/dev/sda6       890G  324G  521G  39% /home
/dev/sdb1       459G  267G  169G  62% /home/user/mnt
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of filtering df output, you can filter its input.

Before:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
C:/Cygwin/bin   150G   76G   74G  51% /usr/bin
C:/Cygwin/lib   150G   76G   74G  51% /usr/lib
C:/Cygwin       150G   76G   74G  51% /
C:              150G   76G   74G  51% /cygdrive/c
```

After:

```
$ mount | grep ^C:/Cygwin | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
C:/Cygwin/bin   150G   76G   74G  51% /usr/bin
C:/Cygwin/lib   150G   76G   74G  51% /usr/lib
C:/Cygwin       150G   76G   74G  51% /
```

*UPDATE 2014-01-24 08:03 UTC: Only grep for C:/Cygwin in the beginning of a line*

Comment: Nice trick but it will not work as expected if you are mounting by UUID instead of device name. The OP wants `df` style output which means `/dev/foo` your command will return `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` format output unless `fstab` contains the `/dev` name.

Comment: The `mount` command uses `/etc/mtab`, which is updated dynamically, and while I am not sure where `df` gets its data from, I suspect that on Linux it reads `/proc/mounts`. Either way I don't understand how `fstab` is relevant and could not reproduce the problem with UUID-mounted disks. Can you elaborate on it?

Answer (score -3):

```
df -h | egrep -e Filesystem -e "/dev" -v
```

Comment: OP has said the heading is locale-dependent, so you can't match it like that. And what is the `sda1` doing at the end?

Comment: @syntaxerror the heading is locale-dependent, as is sorting. So that won't work either, for the same reason. Try `LANGUAGE=ja df -h`, for example. Or Spanish, or French, or many others.