How to ALSO print the first line using grep
I quite often find myself using grep in cases where it would be very handy to have grep print the first line of the result along with the matched lines. This is not limited to Kubernetes (I'm not looking for a Kubernetes specific answer) but for example this command below. Grep gets me the results but I don't have the column headers. The results include several figures that could relate to anything. Same goes if I grep a csv file.
kubectl top pod | grep airflow
The solution I'm looking for is something along these lines, like a combination of head -1 and grep
cat myfile.csv | grep -1 mytext

Add a sample of what you are working with and the expected result to the question. Another tool may be more useful than grep but more information is needed to determine that.

Dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47918/how-to-grep-a-specific-line-and-the-first-line-of-a-file and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105747/grep-lines-but-let-the-first-line-through and similar https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/sort-but-keep-header-line-at-the-top and similar
